# Changing the Wordpress Theme gives [thb_image image] shortcode instead of the image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

So I am trying to change the theme of my WordPress blog. I have visual composer installed. When I try to change the theme, the featured images for the posts show up fine but the in post images are getting replaced by shortcodes like this [thb_image image="1124"][thb_gap height="20"]. What do I need to do to get the images back?

Answer (score 3):

I'm unfamiliar with the `thb_image` shortcode, but it sounds like they are registered inside your old theme, which would explain why they are no longer working when you change themes.

Dig through your old theme files and search for `add_shortcode`. You'll need to find the appropriate ones (`thb_image` and `thb_gap`) and copy them to your current theme's `functions.php` file.

Alternatively, I would wager the `image="1234"` is the ID of the image, and you can just find that in your media library and stick it in the page content using the visual editor.

Comment: So I did search through the old theme, I have files like thb_image.php and thb_gap.php etc in a sub-folder and they have been used in a file named "visualcomposer-extend.php". So what exactly am I supposed to copy in my functions.php?

Comment: Well you'll need to copy all of the code from in them, and based on what's in them, perhaps even the code the calls those two files.